# Error in webservice call

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, soap, asmx

I'm trying to create a webservice between 2 websites, but when I call it I get the following error:

> System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Collections.Generic.KeyNotFoundException: The given key was not present in the dictionary.
>      at CreateAttendee..ctor()
>      --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>      en System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
>      en System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
>      en CreateGlothosAttendee.CreateAttendee.Create(String parameters) en c:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\godigix\0e20025a\e3315649\App_WebReferences.zfpla_cn.0.cs:línea 46
>      en events_EstudiosShopper2015.RegisterAttendee(String name, String email, Boolean acceptNotifications) en f:\SVN\goDigix\Web\www.goDigix.com\events\EstudiosShopper2015.aspx.cs:línea 106

I have the following code to call the webservice:

```
string dataToSend="name=myName&email=myemail@mydomain.com";
WSCreateAttendee.CreateAttendee webService = new CreateAttendee();
string webServiceResponse = webService.Create(dataToSend);
```

And I have the following in my destination:

```
/// <summary>
/// Web service used to create a new company
/// </summary>
[WebService(Namespace = "http://glothos.sureact.com", Name="CreateAttendee")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]

public class CreateAttendee : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public CreateAttendee()
    {
        //do nothing
    }
    [WebMethod]
    public string Create(string parameters)
    {
        //Log into DB the name and email received
    }
}
```

Can anyone help me? I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Thank you

Comment: We can help you once you show us some code

Comment: The exception is thrown in `CreateGlothosAttendee.CreateAttendee.Create()` which does a `new CreateAttendee()`, where you use a `dictionary["key"]` where "key" doesn't exist.

Comment: Hello, I have added more information at my question. But I don't use any "Key" not any "dictionary" in my webservice, or I don't know I'm using them.

Comment: ASMX is a legacy technology, and should not be used for new development. WCF or ASP.NET Web API should be used for all new development of web service clients and servers. One hint: Microsoft has retired the [ASMX Forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/asmxandxml/threads) on MSDN.

Answer (score 0):

The key on this exception is that says [@CodeCaster](https://stackoverflow.com/users/266143/codecaster) at his comment on your question:

> The given key was not present in the dictionary. at CreateAttendee..ctor()

You should ensure that the constructor used on `CreateAttendee` class verifies the existence of the key-identified object before trying to retrieve it.

In example:

```
if (dictionary.ContainsKey("Id"))
{
    value = dictionary["Id"]
}
else
{
    // Act when the key does not exist...
}
```